# SQL selecting the rows with the maximum value in a table ordered by a column from another

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group, groupwise-maximum

I have 2 tables which, simplified, look like this:

```
Name     Server_id     score
-----------------------------
John         1           300
John         2           400
Mary         2           321
John         1           100
Mary         1            50 
Mary         2            10


Server_id     game
-------------------
   1           pong
   2           Mario
```

Each player can have multiple scores associated with any Server. And to a Server, corresponds a game.

Now I want to execute a select statement which returns the maximum score for player, in each game. Something like this:

```
Name     game     score
-----------------------
John     pong     300
John     Mario    400
Mary     pong     50
Mary     Mario    321
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, this is simply a `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
select t1.name, t2.game, max(t1.score)
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.server_id = t2.server_id
 group by t1.name, t2.game;
```